# ng-repeat with one parent list object and multiple child lists objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Edit question :

[Please follow this link in this first add mark is for child row add and 
second add mark is for parent add. in this case when i tried to add first parent of child, 
the child of second parent also adding, as per my issue, it should not be like that.](http://jsfiddle.net/dg12rwex)

my question is :

after looping second list i tried to add internal row(click on +) but it is adding external row in second table also(please refer first image to see screen shot).

Please look into below code,

please refer below image for jsp page  :

```
 <div ng-repeat = "constospopuptablemain in costosPopupTableMainList">
          <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 table-responsive ingpopuptableres" style="float:left;">
       <table class="table table-fixed table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin tablemarg">
        <thead class="evlhead ingpopuphead">
          <tr>

            <th class="evltablethcontreg">Detalle Producto</th>
            <th class="evltablethcontreg">Contidad</th>
            <th class="evltablethcontreg">Unidad de medida</th> 
            <th class="evltablethcontreg">Precio Compra(PC)</th> 
            <th class="evltablethcontreg">Precio Venta(PV)</th>
            <th class="evltablethcontreg">CVTAS</th>
            <th class="evltablethcontreg">Add/Remove</th> 

          </tr>
        </thead> 

        <tbody class="evltbodypopup">
         <tr ng-repeat = "costosmaintablerow in constospopuptablemain.costosMainTableRowList">  

          <td ><input type="text" class="no-marginconreg" ng-model="costosmaintablerow.detalledeproducto"> </td>           
          <td ><input type="text" class="no-marginconreg" ng-model="costosmaintablerow.contidad"></td>
          <td ><input type="text" class="no-marginconreg" ng-model="costosmaintablerow.unidaddemedia"> </td>           
          <td ><input type="text" class="no-marginconreg" ng-model="costosmaintablerow.pc"></td>
          <td ><input type="text" class="no-marginconreg" ng-model="costosmaintablerow.pv"> </td> 
          <td ><input type="text" class="no-marginconreg" ng-model="costosmaintablerow.cvtas"> </td>
          <td ><div class="addrembtn"><input class="btnadd" type="button" value="+" ng-click = "addCostoRow(constospopuptablemain.row,$index)">
          <input class="btnrem" type="button" value="-" ng-click = "removeCostoRow(constospopuptablemain.row,$index)"></div></td>

         </tr>


        </tbody> 
       </table>

       </div> 
       <div style="float:left;"> 
        <button style="background-color: #FAF0E6;width: 68px;margin:55px 0px 0px 4px;font-size: 13px;">+&nbsp;Casto</button>
      </div>

       <div class="Promediodivcosto">
         <label>Promedio</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="tottextfldingpop">
       </div>
       <div class="CostoTotalpopdiv">
         <label>Costo Total</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="tottextfldingpop">
       </div>

       </div>
```

js file :

```
"$scope.costosPopupTableMainList.push($scope.getCostosMainRow(0,$scope.getCostosInternalRowList()));"

$scope.costosMainTableRowList.push($scope.getCostosInternalRowList());
        $scope.costosPopupTableMainList.push($scope.getCostosMainRow(0,$scope.costosMainTableRowList));

$scope.getCostosInternalRowList = function(){

        return costosInternalRows = {

                "detalledeproducto":"",
                "contidad":"",
                "unidaddemedia":"",
                "pc":"",
                "pv":"",
                "cvtas":""

        };
```

the below line for add internal row(child list should repeat once when click on +).

```
$scope.addCostoRow = function(f,e){
    $scope.costosPopupTableMainList[f].costosMainTableRowList.push($scope.getCostosInternalRowList());
}
```

[please refer below image to better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY5bG.png)

[please refer below link for JSP code][3]
for example,

```
<div ng-repeat = "listObj1 in listObjParent">
 <div ng-repeat ="listObj2 in listObj1.listObjchild">

       <input type="text" ng-model = "listObj2"/> <button ng-click="addChilRow()">+</button>
```

for above code, if parent object length is 2 and child object length is 1.
  so parent object will repeats 2 times and child object will available in every parent object.

the issue is,

if i tried to add one extra row(input type element dynamically) in child object of first parent object.
it is also adding in second parent object. but it should not be add like that.
so it means every parent object of child objects should be have different scopes.

i hope that you understand my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't identified a specific problem or question. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: after looping second list i tried to add internal row(click on +) but it is adding  external row in second table also(please refer first image to see screen shot)

Comment: Why did you remove the html....especially after I took the time to properly format all the code so it was readable? Now none of the code is formatted properly

Comment: when i add internal row in first table it should not add internal row in second table. you can see in image

Comment: sorry... i am adding again

Comment: i have added, please check

Comment: when i add internal row in first table there should not be add internal row in second table. you can see in image

Comment: i have edited my question, please verify

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dg12rwex/  ::: Please follow this link

in this first add mark is for child row add and second add mark is for parent add. in this case when i tried to add first parent of child, the child of second parent also adding, as per my issue, it should not be like that.